# Searching Files for a Specific String

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program that will be able to search multiple files and edit a specific string in that and save it back to where it was.

At the moment I have it so it can search the file & display it in a rich text box.

Tells me how many lines are in the files 
and edit a specific line in the file oppose to specific text, are any of you able to help me with this?

```
Public Class Form1

Dim Int1 As Integer

Dim Reader As StreamReader
Dim Lines As String = Int1
Dim Path As String = "C:\Users\callum.hirst\Desktop\DNS\burnsrecruitment.co.uk.dns"
Dim Content As String



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Int1 = New Integer
    Reader = File.OpenText(Path)
    Dim someString As String = "@                       3600    NS  nameserver2.i7net.co.uk." 'this Textbox for searching text example : Yellow
    Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(Path)
    Dim found As Integer = -1
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1 Step i + 1
        If lines(i).Contains(someString) Then
            found = i
            Int1 = i
            MsgBox(Int1)

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Reader = File.OpenText(Path)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What isn't working? It seems to be doing what you want.

Comment: The issue is that line 16 may not be the text that i want to edit it could be on line 22 or line 4 but it is always the same string. I have added this to try and find what line the text i am after is on but i am unable to write to it using the line that is defined

Comment: Please see amended code in the top

Comment: Does your MsgBox display the proper location?

Comment: Dim Lines() As String = System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Users\callum.hirst\Desktop\DNS\burnsrecruitment.co.uk.dns")
        Lines(Int1) = "@                       3600 NS nameserver5.i7net.co.uk."

Comment: Comes up with overload error

Comment: This is the full code and error http://prntscr.com/kve8h9

Comment: As you can see from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2, you need to supply more than one parameter to the method. There are overloads which accept 2, or 3 parameters. That's what the error is telling you. Right now you are telling it to write to a file, but you aren't telling it what data to put in there. BTW this error appears not to be directly related to what you asked about in the question, nor is the code which runs it included in the question. What's the purpose of this extra bit in relation to the issue you were asking about?

Comment: I had the code working but it has now stopped, as you can see from the screen shot it looks for a specific string, and gives me the line number or tells me if it doesn't exist, in the file i know the code is there but now its telling me its not, when it is!!! http://prntscr.com/kveyoz

Comment: well we can't see your file to verify that or not.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kvfqwj

Comment: the actual text of the file in a pastebin would be more helpful, tbh. It could be something as silly as an extra space in one of the strings. Also please update the text of the question with your latest code. If anyone is going to attempt to reproduce your issue they're going to want to copy/paste it, they are never going to re-key all your code and data from a picture. Thanks.